# метод setDocumentViewBox в SVG

Tags: android, svg

Я использую библиотеку androidsvg-1.2.1.jar для рендеринга svg-изображения. Оригинальный размер картинки - 260 пикселей в ширину и 100 пикселей в высоту. Я пыталась установить ширину картинки соразмерно ширине дисплея следующим образом:

```
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int width = size.x;
                int height = size.y;
                height = (int) (width / 2.6);
                svg.setDocumentHeight(height);
                svg.setDocumentWidth(width);
                svg.setDocumentViewBox(0, 0, width, height);
```

В документации написано, что и методы `setDocumentHeight` и `setDocumentWidth`, и метод `setDocumentViewBox` принимают на вход значения в пикселях. Но в этом случае viewbox имел предполагаемый размер, а сама картинка находилась в левой верхнем углу viewbox'а и размер её был гораздо меньше viewbox'а (примерно в 4 раза).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда же я заменила последнюю строку кода на

```
svg.setDocumentViewBox(0, 0, width/4, height/4);
```

то размер картинки стал почти равен размеру viewbox'а, но всё же оставался чуть меньше его. Почему это так происходит? И какие значения должны быть поступать на вход метода `setDocumentViewBox`?

Comment: так какой вопрос, вам необходимо svg в весь родительский элемент разместить? потому что из кода полная неразбериха, это всё делается одной строчкой, зачем и откуда вот это height = (int) (width / 2.6); и зачем вызывать методы поочередно если последний делает ровно то же самое. Возможно если вы опишите суть задачи, будет проще дать ответ, потом что сейчас он бы выглядел: Происходит так как вы такие размеры задали, а должны поступать значения родительского элемента.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, height = (int) (width / 2.6); здесь потому, что мне, как я писала выше, нужно установить ширину картинки соразмерно ширине дисплея, а размер картинки 260*100, следовательно, коэффициент соотношения сторон равен 2,6. И, настолько я понимаю, всё же эти методы не эквиваленты: метод setDocumentViewBox устанавливает высоту и ширину именно изображения, а методы setDocumentHeight и setDocumentWidth  устанавливают начальные координаты и размеры viewport'a - т. е. области просмотра, а её размеры могут и не совпадать с размерами изображения...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я нашла ответ на свой вопрос, прочитав статью [Трансформация изображений SVG при изменении параметров Viewbox](https://svg-art.ru/?p=5)